# integer nth root

Tags: algorithm, math, nth-root

x' is the nth root of y if x' is the largest integer such that x^n <= y. x, x' and y are all integers. Is there any efficient way to compute such nth root? I know this is usually done by [nth root algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm), but the difficulty here is everything is integer because I'm working with an embedded system.

BTW, I've even tried to binary search from 1 to y to identify largest x such that x^n <= y, but it does not work since x^n overflows easily especially when n is large.

Comment: If x^n overflows, how are you storing y?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, given n and y you're looking for x and x' such that x^n <= y <= x'^n ? (x and x' are respectively the largest and smalest integers)

Comment: @Thomas I'm working with maximum of 4 bytes unsigned integer. Say y is 2 ^ 10 and n is 4. My naive algorithm tries all numbers from 1 to 2 ^ 10. When x is 2 ^ 8, oops, (2 ^ 8) ^ 4 = 2 ^ 32, overflow!

Comment: @Ricky Bobby I'm looking for the largest integer x such that x^n <=y

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Store a table for given y of the maximum x such that x^y does not overflow. Use these values for binary search; that way, no more overflow and a neat algorithm that will work as long as x and n have the same (integer) type. Right?

Note: for y > 32, the maximum value for x is 2 for 32-bit integers... in other words, your table will be the same size as the number of bits in integers your system understands, approximately.

Comment: Excellent solution. Sparse on memory, as efficient as it gets.

Comment: @Patrick87 Your solution may not work because for a given n, to find the maximum x such that x^n does not overflow, as you suggest, is equivalent to let y be (2^32 - 1) and solve the original problem I raised. (I'm working with 4 byte unsigned integers)

Comment: @sinoTrinity: not sure what you're talking about. For 4-byte (say unsigned) integers, the table would look like 2->~2^16 3->~2^11, 4->~2^8, ..., 32->2^1, >33->1... then binary search until you hit the cap. Provided n is a valid 32 bit unsigned int, choosing x less than the cap for given x will ensure x^y doesn't overflow. Maybe I misunderstand your problem.

Comment: Also, you precompute this table. Sorry if this wasn't initially clear. As in, make them constants in your program.

Comment: Also, it looks like I'm calling Y what you called N, and vice versa... Sorry if this is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for integer roots only? Or do you want to know that the 5th root of 34 is 2.024...? Or is "2" a sufficient answer? If you want the decimal places, you'll have to do some kind of floating point or fixed point math.

You should read [Computing principal roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Computing_principal_roots), and note what it says about the first Newton approximate. If an error of about 0.03% is close enough, I'd suggest you go with this. You'd probably want to build a table that you can use to do the initial approximations. This table isn't as large as it sounds. The cube root of 2^32 is only about 1,626. You can easily compute the squares, and it's easy to generate x^n if you can generate x^2 and x^3. So doing the approximations is pretty easy.

Another possibility is to build yourself a table of roots and use some kind of interpolation. Again, that table wouldn't have to be very large if you treat the square root as a special case. The 5th root of 2^32 is less than 100, so you're talking a pretty small table to get a pretty large range of roots.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best method is to use the Newton-Raphson method from the Wikipedia article.

A good starting value can be computed from the bit length of the input divided by `n`. In each iteration you use integer division that rounds down. Iterate until you have found a value `x` such that `x^n <= y < (x+1)^n`.

You have to be careful to avoid overflow. As the other answer says, you can use a table of the maximal root for `n < bit size` to do that (for greater `n` the answer is always `1`, except for `y = 0`).