# Wrong answer while calculating the nth root of number in cpp

Tags: c++, algorithm, nth-root

I am calculating the n'th root of a positive integer using standard library method pow() .Here is the snippet from my program :

```
double x,y;
x=pow(64,(1.0/3));
int z;
printf("x=%lf\n",x);
z=(int)x;
printf("%d\n",z);
```

But while finding cube root of 64. X is printed as 4.000000 while z as 3. Why so ?

Can someone suggest a better algorithm , for the same ?

Comment: Types are important, make sure you write `64.0` (double) instead of `64` (integer), same for `3`.  Also, have you included math (I assume you have, but just checking).  Does your compiler provide you any warnings?

Comment: For your particular issue, I suspect your output is being rounded up in printf but your cast is flooring.  Try `int z = round(x);` instead.

Comment: Probably x is something like 3.99999999999737 or otherwise close to 4 and gets rounded by `printf` whilst casting to int just truncates it.

Comment: This is most probably due to floating point precision.

Comment: z=round(x) will give wrong answer for 4th root of 64 @ilent2

Answer (score 2):

If you print more digits on `x`, you'll see what the problem is (I chose 30 randomly):

```
double x ;
x = pow(64, 1.0/3);
printf("x=%.30lf\n",x);
```

Output:

```
x=3.99999999...999600000000
```

So obvisouly, if you cast `x` into a `int` it will became `3`.

There is not a 'perfect' solution. If you're only dealing with integer, you could create your own root function, but if you want to be able to use float, you'need to deal with accuracy problem due to floating point representation.

There are maybe some C libraries which could help you with this kind of problems.

Comment: Can you please tell the root function to find nth root of a integer @Holt

Comment: @Dharmesh I don't know it, but you can find many post on SO like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826822/calculate-nth-root-with-integer-arithmetic or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407752/integer-nth-root.

Answer (score 2):

The `int` override rounds down. Since [floating point operations are inaccurate](http://floating-point-gui.de/), the calculation may be 3.999999...

<strike>Use `round(x)` to get the correct result.</strike>

Since you always want to round *down*, you can use both `floor` and `(int)` -- but you run into the observed error as soon as the instability of floating point calculations results in a *slightly* less value -- something in the order of 10<sup>-15</sup>, for `double` sized calculations. Use a tiny epsilon value to counteract that.

Note that the epsilon "fudge" value below **will** relate to the number of significant digits in your original number. For larger numbers, you need a smaller epsilon.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    double x;
    int z;

    x=pow(64,(1.0/3));
    printf("x=%lf\n",x);
    printf("x=%.30lf\n",x);

    z=(int)x;
    printf("%d\n",z);

    z=(int)(x+0.000000000000005);
    printf("%d\n",z);

    x=pow(64,(1.0/4));
    printf("x=%lf\n",x);
    printf("x=%.30lf\n",x);

    z=(int)x;
    printf("%d\n",z);

    z=(int)(x+0.0000000000000005);
    printf("%d\n",z);

    return 1;
}
```

results, for powers of 1/3 and 1/4, in

```
x=4.000000
x=3.999999999999999555910790149937
3
4
x=2.828427
x=2.828427124746190290949243717478
2
2
```

Comment: z=round(x) will give wrong answer for 4th root of 64 @Jongware

Answer (score 0):

As told by @jongware The **int override rounds down**  and floating point operations may be inaccurate .

though you can always do this to evade this problem

```
def invpow ( n , i):
    x = pow (n ,(1/i))
    if((int)pow((x+1) , i) <= n):
        x += 1;
    print(x)
```

Or you can write your own method for exponentiation by using [Newton - Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-Raphson) method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624602/2875764) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8827111/2875764)

you can also use **Binary search** which is quite fast if you have right guess for the range 
ie (variables high and low )

```
def invpow( x, n, low, high){
    if(n==1)
        return x;
    mid=(low+high)/2;

    while(low<high){
        mid=(low+high)/2;

        raised=pw(mid,n);

        if(raised==x)
            break;

        if(raised>x)
            high=mid;
        else
            low=mid;

        if(low+1==high){
            mid=low;
            break;
            }

    }
    return mid;
}
```